# shell script to use a lookbehind expression

Tags: regex, macos

I'm working on a script that will extract some text from a file after a key word. I'm trying to use a regular expression, but I haven't had luck as of yet. I've tried `grep` and `sed`, but I don't believe that lookbehind expressions are supported in OS X. From what I've read, I need to use `perl` but I can't figure out the syntax. Here's what I have so far

```
result=$(grep "Client Name"  /Users/me/files/test.txt)
```

`$result` gives me a string containing the matching line from the document

Now I want to use a regular expression to select everything that occurs after the word "Client Name". The Regular Expression that seems to work is `(?<=Client Name\s)(?s)(.*$)`

How Can I use perl to store just the matching regEx to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need lookarounds here. You can use `sed` to replace everything before "Client Name" including "Client Name" and any trailing spaces.

```
result=$(grep "Client Name" /Users/me/files/test.txt | sed -e 's/.*Client Name[[:space:]]\{1,\}//')
```

Comment: You can simplify it even further by removing the `grep`, and telling `sed` to only print the line if it gets a match: `sed -ne 's/.*Client Name[[:space:]]\{1,\}//p'`.